# Sql query from database

Tags: php, html, sql, phptal

I need some help with how I can soft query from sql.
I have a php script with an html page who is showing the result from the query.

I have this query:

```
 $ready_orders = DB::query( 'SELECT * FROM ordertable where orderid is NOT null ORDER by id DESC')->fetchAll( DB::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

From the HTML I have this;

```
<tal:block tal:condition="exists:orders">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>amount</td>
      <td> want counter here</td>
      <td>result 1</td>
      <td>result 2</td>
      <td>result 3</td>
      <td>result 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tal:repeat="order orders">
      <td tal:content="">
      ....
      </td>

      <td tal:content="order/id">
      ....
      </td>


      <td tal:content="order/orderid">
      ....
      </td>
      <td tal:content="order/productid">
      ....
      </td>
      <td tal:content="order/processed">
      ....
      </td>

      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The query is doing all I want, but need the result to be in a listing.
Like a counter 1,2,3,4,5 etc

Is it possible?

Comment: everything is possible? what you tried

Answer (score 0):

include a

```
select count * from ordertable
```

Then insert this result in the first

Comment: not working. I shold add something with this php tal? Added the:  <td tal:content="">
      ....
      </td> for the result of the count, but i think this is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can be of much more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(orderid) AS Order_Count
FROM ordertable
WHERE orderid IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

using foreach loop

```
<tal:block tal:condition="exists:orders">
  <table>
   <tr>
      <td>amount</td>
     <?php 
       $i = 1;
       foreach($ready_orders as $result){ ?>
          <td>result <?php echo $i++; ?></td> //your counter
       <?php } ?>
   </tr>

  <tr tal:repeat="order orders">
    <td tal:content="">
        ....
     </td>

  <td tal:content="order/id">
  ....
  </td>


  <td tal:content="order/orderid">
  ....
  </td>
  <td tal:content="order/productid">
  ....
  </td>
  <td tal:content="order/processed">
  ....
  </td>

  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sill not working. Im not so good with the php tal. It wright the query as array. I think i need to put something in the phptal that doest not call to an array

Comment: <tal:block tal:condition="exists:orders">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>amount</td>
      <td> want counter here</td>
      <td>result 1</td>
      <td>result 2</td>
      <td>result 3</td>
      <td>result 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tal:repeat="order orders">
      <td tal:content="">
      ....
      </td>

      <td tal:content="order/id">
      ....
      </td>


      <td tal:content="order/orderid">
      ....
      </td>
      <td tal:content="order/productid">
      ....
      </td>
      <td tal:content="order/processed">
      ....
      </td>

      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

Comment: Not responding on this. The hole query i have is this:               protected $template = 'order.felix';
    
      public function Execute(){
        
   $ready_orders = DB::query( 'SELECT * FROM order_felix  WHERE orderid IS NOT NULL')->fetchAll( DB::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
   
         $this->orders = $ready_orders;